# A/the/any/my salary for this month?

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

> 1 I haven't got a salary for this month.
>
> 2 I haven't got the salary for this month.
>
> 3 I haven't got any salary for this month.
>
> 4 I haven't got my salary for this month.

Some say that 1 and 2 are wrong. Can you explain why it is so, if they are really wrong. If 3 is correct, how can 1 be wrong?

Comment: It's not a question of 'correct or wrong'. but 'more or less idiomatic'. Are you referring to a regular salary which for some reason has not been paid this month, or to being unemployed? If the first, you would probably say "I haven't got/received my salary [for] this month."

Comment: "a regular salary". Don't you find this wrong? " I haven't got a salary for this month." It sounds as if I have more than one salary and I haven't got any of them.

Comment: As you say, (1) is not very idiomatic.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I want to understand the reason why. "I haven't got a present this month" is OK. But what's the problem with "salary"?

Comment: _A salary_ refers to one's regular pay "He was appointed on a salary of £X per month." It would not normally be used of a single month's payment.